Can I Get a High-Level Explanation of the Electron-Builder Code Signing Process?
I inherited an ElectronJS project from a former coworker who worked for a company that we bought but who has since quit and forgotten the details about this project.  No one currently on our team knows anything about this project.  I have figured out how to build the app into an unsigned exe, but I cannot figure out how to sign it, and I am reluctant to buy any certificates to experiment with unless I have a general idea of what to do once I buy one.  Our internal wiki says that this project uses electron-builder to sign the executable.  I found the electron-builder code-signing documentation here:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/code-signing#windows
All that it says is:
To sign an app on Windows, there are two types of certificates:

 * EV Code Signing Certificate
 * Code Signing Certificate

Both certificates work with auto-update. The regular (and often cheaper) Code Signing Certificate shows a warning during installation that goes away once enough users installed your application and you’ve built up trust. The EV Certificate has more trust and thus works immediately without any warnings. However, it is not possible to export the EV Certificate as it is bound to a physical USB dongle. Thus, you can’t export the certificate for signing code on a CI, such as AppVeyor.

If you are using an EV Certificate, you need to provide win.certificateSubjectName in your electron-builder configuration.

If you use Windows 7, please ensure that PowerShell is updated to version 3.0.

I don't know what to do with this information.  It does not appear to outline any steps to take to purchase, download, and install a cert.  Our package.json file makes no mention of a .key, .pem, or .crt file.  I would expect this configuration file to contain the path to the location on my computer where electron-builder can expect to find the certificate I downloaded from the CA.  The only relevant things I see here are:
"build": {
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "icons/winapp.ico",
      "artifactName": "<the filename of the executable to be created>"
    },
}

Does anyone know what I am supposed to do here?  Can you point me in the right direction?  My best guess at this point is that maybe we buy an EV cert dongle from a certificate authority, get it mailed to me, I plug it in and then run the command to build the exe, and it magically works as long as the cert dongle is in the computer, but I don't want to bet $300 on this hunch.  Thanks for any explanation you can provide!

At glance, code signing basically is about to ensure that the executable I got in my computer as a potential user of the application, has not known any kind of code alteration in between. To do that, (since we are talking of windows) windows OS need to be able to make some verification. Firstly it will go look for local certificates (active directory) and then at Microsoft Code Signing certificate store.
So the choices are :



If you are willing to publish your application in the Microsoft
Store you'll need a Microsoft Code Signing certificate




If the application is used internally, you can make your own
Self-signed certificate and tell your local win OS about it, see a
tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqd80Yp9ZSc




Otherwise, if you want to publish your app but not necessary by Microsoft Store, there are many of Certificate Authorities that may
help.



I may suggest to use option 2 in order to test without betting money as it has been said. Then option 1 or 3 as needed.
FYI, when configuring app installer to allow elevation, windows defender will be okay with that without a certificate.
